# Programatically Product Save with Image

Tags: product, image, save, programatically

This is My File Uploader in .phtml file :

```
<input type="file" id="imageUploader"  name="imageUploader">
```

This my PHP file code where form post.

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ExtensionName\Service;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File;

class ImportImageService
{
protected $directoryList;    
protected $file;

    public function __construct(
        DirectoryList $directoryList,
        File $file
    ) {
        $this->directoryList = $directoryList;
        $this->file = $file;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
    $tmpDir = $this->getMediaDirTmpDir();
        /** create folder if it is not exists */
    $this->file->checkAndCreateFolder($tmpDir);
        /** @var string $newFileName */
    //$imageUrl='file:///home/chakko/Downloads/mywatch.jpg';
    $imageUrl=$_FILES['imageUploader']['name'];

    $newFileName = $tmpDir . baseName($imageUrl);
        /** read file from URL and copy it to the new destination */
    $result = $this->file->read($imageUrl, $newFileName);
    if ($result) {
            /** add saved file to the $product gallery */
            $product->addImageToMediaGallery($newFileName, $imageType, true, $visible);
     }
       return $result;
    }
    /**
     * Media directory name for the temporary file storage
     * pub/media/tmp
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getMediaDirTmpDir()
    {
        return $this->directoryList->getPath(DirectoryList::MEDIA) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'tmp';
    }
}
```

The Problem is when I give manually path of the image like         **`$imageUrl='file:///home/chakko/Downloads/mywatch.jpg';`**
 is work good.

But when use `fileuploader` like this         **`$imageUrl=$_FILES['imageUploader']['name'];`**
it will not read the file .

Can any will help me i will be appriciate him

**Ref:**  https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/import-product-image-from-url/

Answer (score 0):

I've had mixed results with the method you have used

Instead I do this

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\Processor $galleryProcessor,
} {
    $this->galleryProcessor = $galleryProcessor;
}
```

https://github.com/DominicWatts/Faker/blob/master/Helper/Product.php#L351

```
$this->galleryProcessor->addImage($product, $newFileName.'.jpg', $imageType, false, $visible);
```

Which is below in core

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Gallery/Processor.php#L133-L154

```
    /**
     * Add image to media gallery and return new filename
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @param string $file file path of image in file system
     * @param string|string[] $mediaAttribute code of attribute with type 'media_image',
     *                                                      leave blank if image should be only in gallery
     * @param boolean $move if true, it will move source file
     * @param boolean $exclude mark image as disabled in product page view
     * @return string
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     * @since 101.0.0
     */
    public function addImage(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        $file,
        $mediaAttribute = null,
        $move = false,
        $exclude = true
    ) {
```

Anyway I use it as part of

```
    public function addImageFromUrl($product, $imageUrl, $visible = false, $imageType = [])
    {
        $tmpDir = $this->getMediaDirTmpDir();
        $this->file->checkAndCreateFolder($tmpDir);
        $newFileName = $tmpDir.basename($imageUrl);
        /** read file from URL and copy it to the new destination */
        $result = $this->file->read($imageUrl, $newFileName);
        $this->file->cp($newFileName, $newFileName.'.jpg');
        if ($result) {
            try {
                // $product->addImageToMediaGallery($newFileName . '.jpg', $imageType, true, $visible);
                $this->galleryProcessor->addImage($product, $newFileName.'.jpg', $imageType, false, $visible);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->logger->critical($e);
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

Maybe that's a bit difficult to follow but I fetch images from an external source.

```
    const PLACEHOLDER_SOURCE = 'http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000';

    public function addImages(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor $product, $limit = 1)
    {
        for ($generate = 1; $generate <= $limit; $generate++) {
            $this->addImageFromUrl($product, self::PLACEHOLDER_SOURCE, true, $generate == 1
                ? ['image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'] : []);
        }
    }
```

And set first image as default for 'image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'

Works for me.